python running in cursor can't see an installed package. What makes packages visible in python?
I wrote code using pygame, and so installed it:
pip install pygame

From the command line, the code works.
In cursor (an AI-enabled editor that appears to be based on vscode) though, it shows up as missing, and when I try to run the program,
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named pygame

I killed the editor, started again from the command line that works. Same error.
I tested it in VSCode, and it's the same, so it has nothing to do with cursor specifically.
I understand linux PATH, but not whatever mechanism is searching for packages in Python.
How do I get the environment in the IDE to match what I can do on the command line?
And why doesn't it match what I've installed in pip on my account?

Backgraound read:
Just like with Linux PATH (used to find Python interpreter), there is an environment variable to tell Python where to look for libraries, PYTHONPATH.
Combined with a few other variables, this allows to create a set of folders with an isolated set of modules and binaries - including a non-system-default Python. The most famous is the built-in venv, but there are others, like pipenv, conda, etc.
Most IDEs, including vscode, include tools to work with these environments, and often create them for your project by default.
Finally, the answer:
Check your project interpreter settings and set it to use system Python or install needed libraries into the virtual environment created for your project.
